# How to calculate the correct height for an auto-expanding textbox in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

In my Silverlight app I want a multi-line text box to expand every time the user hits Enter.

The difficult part is how to calculate the correct height based on the number of text lines.

I have tried the following but the textbox becomes too small:

```
box.Height = box.FontSize*lineCount + box.Padding.Top + box.Padding.Bottom + box.BorderThickness.Top + box.BorderThickness.Bottom;
```

What am I missing here? Or maybe it can be done automatically somehow?

Thanks,
Jacob

**Edit:** I suspect the problem to be in the FontSize property (does it use another size unit?)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be how the textbox works out of the box. Just make sure you set the [AcceptsReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.acceptsreturn(VS.95).aspx)="True" on the textbox. Also make sure you don't set the height of the Textbox so that it is calculated for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` will fire a `SizeChanged` event, and it will also set the `ActualHeight` property.

I don't think this was the case in Silverlight 2, when I had to use a `TextBlock` with the same font, set the padding to 4, and set the same text, and get the `ActualHeight` off that.